# Решить логическую задачу на языке Prolog (Strawberry)

Tags: prolog

> Перед началом шахматного матча болельщики обсуждали шансы сильнейших
>   участников предстоящего состязания: **Пешкина**, **Ладейникова**,
>   **Королева** и **Слонова**. Все сходились на том, что этой четверке обеспечены первые 4 места в турнирной таблице. А более подробные
>   прогнозы болельщики предпочитали высказывать в несколько туманной
>   форме. Вот что они говорили:
>
> ***1-й болельщик:*** Все они наберут разное количество очков. Дележки мест в таблице не будет. Если Пешкин не займет первое место, то
>   Королеву достанется лишь четвертое.
>
> ***2-й болельщик:*** Если Королев займет третье место, то Пешкин займет четвертое. Но у Пешкина положение в турнирной таблице должно
>   быть лучше, чем у Слонова.
>
> ***3-й болельщик:*** Если Ладейников не завоюет первое место, тогда Пешкин выйдет на третье место. А если Королеву удастся занять второе
>   место, то Слонов, конечно, не будет на четвертом месте.
>
> ***4-й болельщик:*** Если Королев займет первое место, то вторым будет Слонов. А если Слонов не будет на втором месте, то и Ладейников не
>   займет второго места.
>
> И представьте себе, ни один из прогнозов не разошелся с истинным
>   результатом матча.
>   **Вопрос:** Кто какие места занял?

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy, видимо "Кто какие места занял?" в пункте про 4 болельщика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solve(Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff):-
    place(Peshkin),place(Ladeynikoff),place(Korolyov),
    place(Slonoff),
    Peshkin\=Ladeynikoff,
    Peshkin\=Korolyov,
    Peshkin\=Slonoff,
    Ladeynikoff\=Korolyov,
    Ladeynikoff\=Slonoff,
    Korolyov\=Slonoff,
forecast(1,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff),
forecast(2,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff),
forecast(3,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff),
forecast(4,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff),
write("\nSolve:\nPeshkin:"),
write(Peshkin),
write("\nLadeynikoff:"),
write(Ladeynikoff),
write("\nKorolyov:"),
write(Korolyov),
write("\nSlonoff:"),
write(Slonoff),nl.
place(Place):- Place = 1;Place = 2;Place = 3;Place = 4.
forecast(1,Peshkin,_,Korolyov,_):- 
        Peshkin> 1,Korolyov = 4.

forecast(2,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff):-
        Korolyov=3,Peshkin=4;
        Peshkin<Slonoff.
forecast(3,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff):-
        Ladeynikoff>1,Peshkin=3;
        Korolyov\=2,Slonoff<4.
forecast(4,Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff):-
        Korolyov=1,Slonoff=2;
        Slonoff\=2,Ladeynikoff\=2.
```

---

Решить:

```
?- solve(Peshkin,Ladeynikoff,Korolyov,Slonoff).
```

Ответ:

```
 Peshkin:2
 Ladeynikoff:1
 Korolyov:4
 Slonoff:3
```